Remove "additionalProp1": {} from swagger-ui
I want to do swagger docs for my api (written on golang).
I have some type for response:
// @Description response format
type Response map[string]interface{}

When I init swagger docs, I am getting:
"definitions": {
        "song.Response": {
            "description": "response format",
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": true
        },

How can I set additionalProperties=false for remove "additionalProp1": {} from swagger-ui ?
{
  "error": {
    "message": "string",
    "path": "string",
    "timestamp": "string",
    "additionalProp1": {}
  },
  "additionalProp1": {}
}

I have tried already to set false by hands in template in generated docs.go and "additionalProp1": {} removed from swagger-ui.
But docs.go is DO NOT EDIT file (generated)
